# Accessing USB device using firefox

Tags: firefox, usb, libusb

Is there any way to access an USB device through Firefox on a local computer?

More details: I have created a USB device using microchip 18F2250 that sends data of thermal and humidity sensors & able to receive data to control a robotic arm..

The device has been tested on a C#2010 program to access the USB device successfully..

Now I run a HTML/javascript web page as a local server (http://localhost:8000/..bla bla bla..) & I need to access the USB device from this firefox bowser..

Notes : cannot use Chrome and its plug in WebUSB, I'm restricted to Firefox only for some reasons.

Any help??